# how can I set the controller in the scene builder?

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to use `sceneBuilder` for a `javaFx` application. I have a `Package` that is called `testPac` and inside that I have the folders as has been presented in figure 1;

[image: figure 1]

I have one `fxml` file and its `controller` inside the `view` folder.
now, I don't know what I must use inside the controller box in `sceneBuilder`. 
the content of `view` folder according to figure 2.

[image: figure 2]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just need to specify the *fully-qualified classname*, i.e. `packagename.ClassName`. So, if I understand your project structure correctly, your controller class is `scaterChartController`<sup>1</sup> and it is in a package called `testPac.view`<sup>1,2</sup>. So your `fx:controller` attribute should have the value `fx:controller = "testPac.view.scaterChartController"`.

In SceneBuilder you can set this in the "Controller" pane which is in the bottom left of the screen (expand it if necessary):

[image]

---

### Footnotes:

1. You should follow [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java), so all class names should begin with an upper case letter. `scaterChartController` is not a proper class name according to the standard convention. Similarly, package names should be all lower case, so "a package called `testPac`" also violates the convention.
2. The package name is evident from the first line of code. I am assuming you have a package name of `view`, so the first line of code in the controller class will be

   ```
   package testPac.view ;
   ```

   Modify the `fx:controller` attribute accordingly if the package is different to that.

Comment: thank you, I must of spent an hour looking for that Controller drop down. When I first open up builder, it's located at the very bottom left hand corner - hidden in plain view.